# select-object cmdlet takes 13 mins for fetching 1000 SharePoint users using get-spuser through C# remotely

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

I am using PowerShell cmdlet `Get-SPUser` through C# program remotely as follows

```
Get-SPUSer -Web <siteCollection> | Select-Object -property Name,LoginName....
```

After I invoke this command it gives me output in form of `Collection<PSObject>`

This command is taking 13 minutes for fetching just 1000 users. Isn't it too long? This is when I fired it remotely and via C# program.

When I trigger the same command using PowerShell command prompt, it returns within a few seconds.

Why it is taking so long time when fired remotely via C# program?

I am using .NET framework is 4.0 and Visual Studio 2013. Same results with .NET framework 2.0/3.5 and Visual Studio 2005.

Any clue or workaround how to improve performance of `select-object` cmdlet?
Can anybody give a concrete solution?

Comment: If you do it using a c# program, why don´t you use the c# Client-API? Do you use a remote-powershell?

Comment: @Leopold - Client API does not provide all properties of sharepoint user ! 
Yes I do use powershell remotely. PowerShell command users Server API internally so that is why I get all properties of user. I don't want to use Server API as I have requirement to connect sharepoint server remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your own webservice to sharepoint. You could call that service remote and process the response.

But you might not have a chance to speed up the powershell-remoting-process. this does not belong to sharepoint itself.